# How to expand toastr thing in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, toastr, angular-toastr, ngx-toastr

I have a **ToastrService** imported from 'ngx-toastr' in my Angular 2 app. The problem is that the text which I show there does not fit in, and it gets cut.

Can I expand it somewhere?

Eg, I can set up some params in toastrConfig:

```
const toastrConfig: Partial<IndividualConfig> = {
                            timeOut: 20000,
                            extendedTimeOut: 20000
                          }; 
this.toastr.warning(message, null, toastrConfig);
```

But I didn't find any settings in `IndividualConfig` regarding how wide/narrow should the pop up be.

Comment: I don't think it would be a very good UX to show the user a very long message in a toast. Considering that the message doesn't fit in the toast, it's probably very long, which doesn't suit for a toast to show as they are meant to show just some notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, toastr expands as needed. The problem was that there was a '<' thing in a message which toastr treated as a beginning of html tag. Damn.